# How to make zsh completion like bash

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am using zsh. It is a nice shell, especially for the auto completion function. But, when I press tab, it always auto fill with the first completion option. For example, there are two files in my folder.

```
Mydata.txt
YourData.txt
```

If I type `vim`, a blank, then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, it will auto fill with `Mydata.txt` instead of just list them and wait for my input. I do not like to keep on pressing tab to choose the files. It is more easier to press some letters.

I have tried to revise .zshrc and set

```
unsetopt MENU_COMPLETE
```

But, it doesn't work.

Could anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a answer by myself. If I set

zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:default' menu no select

Then I can input characters to select the autocomplete options. Though, I can not select by list.

Comment: fyi, this setting will not be applied if you are using ohmyzsh. to make it stick, you have to add this line to a file like `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/myfile.zsh`

Answer (score 10):

For reference, and as I'm not completely sure, how `bash` behaves exactly, I quote from the [*A User's Guide to the Z-Shell*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/) by Peter Stephenson, the current maintainer of `zsh`.

> **6.2.1 Ambiguous completions**
>
> The largest group of options deals with what happens when a completion
>   is ambiguous, in other words there is more than one possible
>   completion. The seven relevant options are as follows, as copied from
>   the FAQ; many different combinations are possible:
>
> - with **NO_BEEP** set, that annoying beep goes away,
> - with **NO_LIST_BEEP**, beeping is only turned off for ambiguous completions,
> - with **AUTO_LIST** set, when the completion is ambiguous you get a list without having   to type `CTRL+D`,
> - with **BASH_AUTO_LIST** set, the list only happens the second time you hit tab on an   ambiguous completion,
> - with **LIST_AMBIGUOUS**, this is modified so that nothing is listed if there is   an unambiguous prefix or suffix to be inserted -- this can
>     be combined with   **BASH_AUTO_LIST**, so that where both are applicable
>     you need to hit tab three times   for a listing,
> - with **REC_EXACT**, if the string on the command line exactly matches one of the possible   completions, it is accepted, even if there is
>     another completion (i.e. that string with   something else added) that
>     also matches,
> - with **MENU_COMPLETE** set, one completion is always inserted completely, then when you   hit `TAB` it changes to the next, and so on
>     until you get back to where you started,
> - with **AUTO_MENU**, you only get the menu behaviour when you hit TAB again on the   ambiguous completion.

You probably want to use (but as I'm said I'm not sure, please feel free to correct me)

```
setopt BEEP NO_AUTOLIST BASH_AUTOLIST NO_MENUCOMPLETE
```

where `setopt NO_OPTION` is equivalent to `unset OPTION`.

Comment: Perfect answer - I appreciated the description of the different settings. Stepping through enabling or disabling each one along with the descriptions made it much clearer to me what was needed to be changed and why.

Comment: 1: I think that should say `NO_MENU_COMPLETE` (note the missing underscore). 2: That option didn't actually help me, I had to set `NO_AUTO_MENU` instead.

Comment: @CamJackson: 1. The underscores are irrelevant, `MENU_COMPLETE`, `MENUCOMPLETE` as well es `MENUCOMP_LETE` work exactly the same. 2. Thanks for posting your experience with `NO_AUTO_MENU`.

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
 setopt autolist
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, Jens, I used "setopt auto list, unset MENU_CoMPLETE", but, it does not work.