# Possible to get Bash like tab completion in ZSH?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

If you do the following in Bash

```
$ touch b bb bbb
$ ls b* # press tab twice
b    bb   bbb
```

If you do the same in ZSH you get

```
➜ ls b bb bbb
```

ZSH expand the matches to the command and hence removes the `*`.

When I Google [this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=zsh%20don%27t%20expand%20tab%20completion) they are all about some other form of tab completion.

**Question**

Is it possible to get ZSH to have the same tab completion as Bash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make zsh completion like bash](https://superuser.com/questions/602882/how-to-make-zsh-completion-like-bash)

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @mpy No it still expands...

Comment: Oh, I see, retracting my close vote. Can you try `bindkey "^I" complete-word` as mentioned in my answer [there](https://superuser.com/a/800131/195224). With that I got rather similar behavior between _bash_ and _zsh_, but neither lists the possible choices after `b*` as you describe. Do you use some non-standard bash options?

Comment: @mpy When I try that, it doesn't expand, but it doesn't show which that makes either that Bash does.

Comment: @Sandra Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

For more info, read the [Zsh completion manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html).